# Blog Engine with text/html syntax and file-based input

Tags: python, blogs

I am looking for a blog engine which has the following features:

1. Should be able to accept posts in either pure text or HTML.
2. I should be able to blog offline and then update the things online with a single command. This will most probably require git.
3. The files should be stored in "human-readable format" and I should be able to move them easily.
4. I have no preference about the database. I am comfortable moving a database around if need be.
5. People should be able to suscribe to my blog using RSS or Atom feed.
6. It should preferably run on python framework. (No reason for it, but I suspect python solutions would be better.)
7. It should look good!! (preferably).

Anything special that you recommend for this?

EDIT: blog offline means, I should be able to use any kind of editor I want to generate the HTML file which I want to put in the blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Blogofile](http://www.blogofile.com/).

Comment: nice one..... as much as i have seen of it...
will try and let you know the exact results...
looks like what i want though from the features......

Comment: yes.. this is what I want!! Have been using for half an hour now...
Really good.!! Thanks